# Angular component styleUrls

Tags: angular, webpack-2

We are using Angular 6 with WebPack 3 (no Angular CLI).
We want to have a css file inline.

This works:
     `styles: [require('./appel.css')]`

This doesn't work:
     `styleUrls: ['./appel.css']`

In webpack we have following rule:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   loader: 'raw-loader'
}
```

How can we have this working with styleUrls?

The reason is that we are using a third party angular module in node_modules which is using styleUrls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your webpack config need changes. You should distinguish between global styles and component styles, try this.

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   includes: [
      path.join(_dirname, 'src/main/webapp/app')
   ]
   loader: [
        'raw-loader',
        'css-loader'
   ]
}
```

Comment: I tried the following because includes is not recognized and loaders has to be used for array but with no luck. The browser still tries to download a css file which doesn't exist.{
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'raw-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]